# Python regex match only if standalone

Tags: python, regex

Using re in python3, I want to match appearances of percentages in text, and substitute them with a special token (e.g. substitute "A 30% increase" by "A @percent@ increase").

I only want to match if the percent expression is a standalone item. For example, it should not match "The product's code is A322%n43%". However, it should match when a line contains only one percentage expression like "89%".

I've tried using delimiters in my regex like \b, but because % is itself a non-alphanumeric character, it doesn't catch the end of the expression. Using \s makes it impossible to catch expression standing by themselves in a line.

At the moment, I have the code:

```
>>> re.sub(r"[+-]?[.,;]?(\d+[.,;']?)+%", ' @percent@ ', "1,211.21%")
' @percent '
```

which still matches if the expression is followed by letters or other text (like the product code example above).

```
>>> re.sub(r"[+-]?[.,;]?(\d+[.,;']?)+%", ' @percent@ ', "EEE1,211.21%asd")
'EEE @percent@ asd'
```

What would you recommend?

Comment: Try [`re.sub(r'(?<!\w)-?\d[\d.,]*\b%\B', '@percent@', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/cSDj19/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a perfect job for Negative Lookbehind and Negative Lookahead:

```
re.sub(r'''(?<![^\s]) [+-]?[.,;]? (\d+[.,;']?)+% (?![^\s.,;!?'"])''', 
       '@percent@', string, flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

`(?<![^\s])` means "no space immediately before the current position is allowed" (add more forbidden characters if you need).

`(?![^\s.,;!?'"])` means "no space, period, etc. immediately after the current position are allowed".

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/khV7MZ/1.

Comment: Great answer. The suggestion works perfect, includes more cases than I considered (e.g. it perfectly detects 5% in "Did you say 5%?"), and the tool you link to is super useful! Thanks.

Comment: are the spaces in your regex ignored? is that because they're in between triple quote?

Comment: @AndresSuarez The spaces are ignored because of `flags=re.VERBOSE` (but in `[ ]`, spaces wouldn't be ignored). Triple quotes are used to avoid escaping of `'` and `"`.

Comment: Note taken! Thks @Kirill

Answer (score 0):

Try putting  "first" capture group with a "second".

```
original: r"[+-]?[.,;]?(\d+[.,;']?)+%"
suggestd: r"[+-]?[.,;]?((\d+[.,;']?)+%)\b"
```

Comment: this didn't work for, it still doesn't detect the word boundary. It doesn't work, with "3%" in a line, by itself, for example